# How to style one of the li that generate with repeat.for in aurelia?

Tags: sass, aurelia

```
<ul>
  <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" > ${row.title} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

> infact i want to style one of the router button that generate with *repeat.for* method

[want to make left border radius for navigation bar like the right of the navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbTlY.png)

Comment: why not use a css class for your `<li />` and style that?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts i want to style the very first li actually there is navbar list and i want to the first li that create have border-top/bottom-left-radius: blah;

Comment: You can identify the first repeated element with the $index context variable.
This would lead to something like this:
<ul>
  <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" >
   <a if.bind="$index === 0" class="blah"> ${row.title} </a>
   <a else class="another class"> ${row.title} </a>
  </li>
</ul>

Comment: @CristiánOrmazábal would you mind posting that as an answer, so I can give you an upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a one-liner option, you could bind your class attribute with ...

```
 <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" class="${myBool ? 'a-class' : 'another-class'}">${row.title}</li>
```

You can bind class with string interpolation or with .bind syntax.  See https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/class-and-style#class

UPDATE:  Sorry...should have read your other comment further down.  If it's just for the first , why not just use CSS?

```
#myUl>li:first-child{
   // my CSS here
}​
```

Comment: thank you its work but i wanted to know that, can i get the specific li or something else that aurelia generate... by the way its work.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the first repeated element with the $index context variable.
This would lead to something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" >
   <a if.bind="$index === 0" class="blah"> ${row.title} </a>
   <a else class="another class"> ${row.title} </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you need to do the styling on the `<li>` tag, the solution could be like this:

```
<ul>
  <template repeat.for="row of router.navigation" >
    <li if.bind="$index === 0" class="blah"> ${row.title} </li>
    <li else class="another class"> ${row.title} </li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

Comment: i want to style the upper li can you be more specific?

Comment: FYI, you can just use $first and $last as well for this